# Script to disable "Get to Google faster. Add Google to your start screen."

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, google-search

Every time I open google homepage in Firefox I keep getting this really annoying message below the address bar as shown below.
 [image: Get to Google faster. Add Google to your start page.]

I often delete history(cache), so even if I click "No Thanks", it appears again. Is there a script to disable it permanently.

Is it possible to remove the "Install Google Chrome" ad from the Google home page.

[image]

**Edit:** There seems to be no solution neither on the internet nor from the users here, so I formed my own script. Works fine. Please refer my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install **Greasemonkey** addon to firefox and add the following script.

`google.promos&&google.promos.toast && google.promos.toast.cpc();
window.google.promos.pushdown.pd_tp = function(){return false;};`

*If you want to understand how it works, read further.*

***Removing the Chrome promo-box:*** The first line of the code invokes the function that executes when we click the close button on the chrome promo-box.

***Disabling the push-down bar:*** Unfortunately, this task is not as easy as the previous one, because the push-down bar activates after a short delay (clever programming by the google folks). So, our only choice is to remove the contents of the function that initiates the push-down event. The second line accomplishes this effectively.